# Como simular click de botão em jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho uma função que executa ao clicar em um botão em `jQuery`.

```html
    $('.btnEntrega').click(function (e) {=
     idPrograma = $(this).data('id');

     CoresFormasPlacas($(this).data('placa'), $(this).data('especie'), $(this).data('categoria'), $(this).data('tipo'));

     $('#modalConfirmaEntrega #exampleModalLongTitleAuto').html("<br/> Autorização: " + $(this).data('autorizacao'));
     ConfirmaEntrega("Confirma a Entrega?");

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

 });
```

Gostaria que quando outro botão fosse clicado, ele chamasse essa mesma função, então fiz o seguinte:

```html
$('.btnDigital').click(function () {
  $(".btnEntrega").click();
});
```

Mas isso não funciona, e não me traz nenhum erro.
Como faço para chamar a função de cima quando o botão "btnDigital" é clicado?

Comment: já tentou: `$('#botao').trigger('click');`

Comment: Tentei sim, mas não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, eu criaria uma função para o código que você quer executar pelos dois botões. Não é uma boa ideia fazer um botão depender do outro, porque se um deixa de existir o outro para de funcionar, entre outros fatores de arquitetura.

Tenta assim:

```js
function entrega(object) {
     idPrograma = object.data('id');

     CoresFormasPlacas(object.data('placa'), object.data('especie'), object.data('categoria'), object.data('tipo'));

     $('#modalConfirmaEntrega #exampleModalLongTitleAuto').html("<br/> Autorização: " + object.data('autorizacao'));
     ConfirmaEntrega("Confirma a Entrega?");
}


$('.btnEntrega').click(function (e) {=
     entrega($(this));

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

 });

$('.btnDigital').click(function (e) {
     entrega($(this));

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Para disparar eventos automáticos: trigger / triggerHandler.

```
$('.btnDigital').click(function () {
    $(".btnEntrega").trigger('click');
});
```

[Documentação jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: Tentei sim, mas até onde eu sei, o .trigger('click') é só um atalho para o .click() então o erro continua ocorrendo.

Comment: Trigger não é um atalho de clique, a função `trigger()` força um evento simulando uma determinada função, como o "click" sem precisar da ação do usuário, lembrando que alguns eventos são bloqueados, por regras de segurança nos navegadores, e que por sua vez, são impedidos de serem acionados automaticamente, dependendo dos riscos, mas como vc está executando uma função de clique, manualmente, acredito que essa regra é permissiva.

Comment: Entendi, já usei Trigger várias vezes, mas neste caso não funcionou. A solução de @boolean foi a que funcionou para mim...

Comment: A solução do @boolean faz todo o sentido, já que vc está só herdando para um outro botão a mesma ação, seria mais inteligente criar um método que pode ser chamado, Dá pra melhorar isso, usando uma classe, é sempre melhor trabalhar com herança e polimorfismo.